# Maintain SQLite Database in Intent Service with AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-service, intentservice

I have implemented code **Sending new data to Server** and **Receiving New data from Server** in following way.

#### First of all Receiving New Data:

```
public class ReceivingOrderService extends IntentService {

    public ReceivingOrderService() {
    super("ReceivingDataService");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /*
     * Context Variable
     */
    Context context;

    /*
     * Database Variable
     */
    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;


    /** 
     *  For Sending LastSyncTime to Server 
     **/
    String last_sync_time;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /*
     * Getting Context Object
     */
    context = getApplicationContext();

    /* 
     * Getting Database Object and Opening DB
     */
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    dbHelper.open();

    /*
     * Getting last_sync_time
     */
    last_sync_time = dbHelper.getLastSyncTime();

    if(last_sync_time == null)
    {
        this.stopSelf();
        last_sync_time = null;
    }

    new ReceiveDataTask().execute();
    }

    public class ReceiveDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,JSONObject>
    {

        /***********
         *
         *
         * PROCESS for RECEIVING and UPDATING DB
         *
         *
         ***********/

        /**** DATABASE CLOSING *****/

        /**** starting Service for Sending New Data *****/
    }
}
```

#### then Sending Data:

```
public class SendingOrderService extends IntentService {
   new SendingDataTask().execute();
}

public class SendDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,JSONObject>
{

}
```

Everything is going well but sometimes application gives error of `Force Close` because of Database.

> I think problem is occurred when i am querying database at the same
>   time service also going to call database.

1. Is maintaining of Database in IntentService is wrong? is there any other Way?
2. Can i send Request directly to server without using AsyncTask?

Your Help would be Appreciated.

Comment: If you have a crash, post a stack trace from logcat.

Comment: why do you need a asynctask in intent service?

Comment: You don't need the AsyncTask inside the IntentService. All the code inside of `onHandleIntent` is already going to be executed on a background thread.

Comment: Ok. I have removed AsyncTask and posted whole code in `onHandleIntent`. My other question is how database will maintaining in Service.

Comment: And be careful sqllite actions are blocking the UI Thread. If you are planning to use the IntentService as a background thread and to keep the UI responsive, take care to make short and just few operations on your database...

Answer (score 0):

You should use only 1 instance of dbHelper in the application and service. Coordinating with synchronized stament when opening and executing closing the database.

Comment: Can you give me Example.